# Why is std::vector::iterator not contiguous iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, type-traits, c++20, c++-concepts

According to the [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::vector`:

> `iterator` LegacyRandomAccessIterator

Also from another [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator):

> The following standard library types are *LegacyContiguousIterators*:
>
> `vector::iterator` for value_type other than bool.

**Which is correct?**

Comment: Both are correct. Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain. One is wishful thinking. The other is cold, hard, reality.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik huh?

Comment: Huh what, @Quentin? You've never heard of `std::vector<bool>`, and all of its awesomeness? And what mess it has created, going on multiple decades now? Well, you're in for a treat. Just start at www.google.com, and keep reading...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have, but that quote (?) went right over my head :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` (for `T` other than `bool`) *is* a contiguous iterator.

[[vector.overview]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview#2):

> A `vector` meets all of the requirements of a container and [...] for an element type other than `bool`, of a contiguous container.

[[container.requirements.general]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#13) (emphasis mine):

> A contiguous container is a container whose member types iterator and const_iterator meet the Cpp17RandomAccessIterator requirements ([random.access.iterators]) and **model contiguous_­iterator** ([iterator.concept.contiguous]).

---

> According to the [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::vector`:
>
> > `iterator` LegacyRandomAccessIterator

It doesn't mean that the iterator is not a contiguous iterator. It's not even talking about contiguous iterator.

The same page also mentions:

> `std::vector` (for `T` other than `bool`) meets the requirements of [...] *ContiguousContainer* [...].

And [the page of ContiguousContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer) says:

> The type `X` satisfies *ContiguousContainer* if
>
> - [...]
> - The member types `X::iterator` and `X::const_iterator` are *LegacyContiguousIterators*

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct. All vector iterators are random access iterators. All vector iterators except those of vector of bool are contiguous iterators. Note that all contiguous iterators are also random access iterators.

The former claim does simply not provide as much information, and may have not been updated since changes from c++17 which introduced the name for for the requirements of contiguous iterator.