# Why is std::vector<int>::iterator not a contiguous iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

According to the standard, as quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61140102/634821), `vector<T>::iterator` should be contiguous (for `T` other than `bool`), but in all the 3 main implementations it is not, why?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using InputIterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category, std::contiguous_iterator_tag>);
```

The first `static_assert` succeeds, but the 2nd fails with the latest MSVC, GCC and clang.

https://godbolt.org/z/oG1x1xdda

Comment: Reading about [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) it says that `iterator_category` is for *legacy* iterator categories, while `iterator_concept` is for modern iterator concepts. Try checking `iterator_concept` instead.

Comment: There is so much code that depends on the `iterator_category` being `random_access_iterator_tag ` that it hasn't been changed to `contiguous_iterator_tag`. Note that the iterator category is not the same as the concept `contiguous_­iterator`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I see! I have only now realized that I'm checking for `is_same_v`, so there's no way it could be true for both, but I initially expected that it will be both a random access iterator and a contiguous iterator, which isn't possible - at least not when tested in this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector<int>::iterator` *is* a contiguous iterator in the sense that it satisfies the [`std::contiguous_iterator`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#concept:contiguous_iterator) concept and the *[contiguous iterator](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#def:contiguous_iterators)* requirements.

`std::iterator_traits` does not test whether something satisfies the *[contiguous iterator](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#def:contiguous_iterators)* requirements, since these are semantic requirements.
Not even pointers have a `contiguous_iterator_tag` as their `iterator_category`, as specified in [[iterator.traits] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#5). The only way that any type has this tag is through specializing `std::iterator_traits`.

You should use the relevant concepts to test whether `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a random access iterator, or even contiguous iterator:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>); // OK
static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>);    // OK
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o48ojjb1o)*

Note that this test may have false positives. As stated in [[iterator.concept.contiguous] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#2), `std::contiguous_iterator` has additional semantic constraints, and the concept may be *satisfied* even if the iterator doesn't *model* a contiguous iterator.

Also note that `std::iterator_traits` may also have an `iterator_concept` alias member, but only for pointers or if the user specialized `std::iterator_traits` for their type. It is not guaranteed to exist, and you should use the concepts directly.